# Red Hat OpenStack 10 can you generate a overcloudrc file if the original is deleted?

Tags: openstack

Is it possible to generate a new overcloudrc file? One is created during deployment but ours was deleted during some other issues.

If someone knows the command to do so....

Answer (score 0):

Take some overcloudrc, change IPs with control plane VIP, you can get this from any of the controller nodes (I hope you still have stackrc, which has only undercloud IP as variable). For OS_PASSWORD, you can login to any of the overcloud controller node and get the output of "sudo hiera keystone::admin_password".

I hope this will solve your problem.